# How to disable rpc token in GWT

Tags: gwt, gwt-rpc, gwt2

I'm using GWT 2.10.0, and I'd like to deactivate the RPC token only during development, but have it activated in production. Any suggestions on how I can achieve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't quite clear what you're asking or how you've implemented your own token approach already, so to restate, you have a `com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.RpcToken` implementation that can be serialized, and a `com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.XsrfProtect` annotation on your RemoteService type. Then you extended `XsrfProtectedServiceServlet` to provide your server-side implementation of the `RemoteService`.

`XsrfProtectedServiceServlet` extends `AbstractXsrfProtectedServiceServlet`, which extends `RemoteServiceServlet` itself. `RemoteServiceServlet provides an empty method` onAfterRequestDeserialized`that can be overridden, and`AbstractXsrfProtectedServiceServlet` provides a simple implementation, shared below:

```java
  @Override
  protected void onAfterRequestDeserialized(RPCRequest rpcRequest) {
    if (shouldValidateXsrfToken(rpcRequest.getMethod())) {
      validateXsrfToken(rpcRequest.getRpcToken(), rpcRequest.getMethod());
    }
  }
```

Then `AbstractXsrfProtectedServiceServlet` provides a simple protected implementation of `shouldValidateXsrfToken`, but leaves `validateXsrfToken` abstract, so that your superclass, `XsrfProtectedServiceServlet`, can override it. Both of these seem like a reasonable extension point to provide custom functionality - you can override either method, and if you determine you are running in production, call super, otherwise if you are in development/test, ignore the rest of the check and simply return success.

For example, assuming you have a `isRunningInProduction()` method (up to you to implement, either of these should solve your problem:

```java
  @Override
  protected boolean shouldValidateXsrfToken(Method method) {
    if (isRunningInProduction()) {
      super.shouldValidateXsrfToken(method);
    }
    // not in production, skip validation
    return false;
  }
```

or

```java
  @Override
  protected void validateXsrfToken(RpcToken token, Method method)
      throws RpcTokenException {
    if (isRunningInProduction()) {
      super.validateXsrfToken(token, method);
    }
    // not in production, do nothing
  }
```

Note that providing both will also work, but only `shouldValidateXsrfToken` will ever be called.